# why does my listbox on click puts today's date

Tags: vba, date, listbox, userform

I have a userform  that I use to enter my Purchase order information into. Then when I need to update the information I search by the PO#  and the record is displayed in my listbox. Everything is working fine except that when I click on the listbox entry to populate my userform it enters today's date instead of the date already in the record.

I am quite new to VBA so I'm sure you all will see where I can trim my code. But all I need is for the listbox to tranfer the exact information in the record to my userforms

```
Private Sub lstdisplay_Click()

If lstdisplay <> "" Then

    Me.txtPO.Value = Me.lstdisplay.Column(0)
    Me.txtconf.Value = Me.lstdisplay.Column(1)
    Me.txtVendor.Value = Me.lstdisplay.Column(2)
    Me.txtname.Value = Me.lstdisplay.Column(3)
    Me.txtPODate.Value = Me.lstdisplay.Column(4)
    Me.txtPOamt.Value = Me.lstdisplay.Column(6)
    Me.txtpaidamt.Value = Me.lstdisplay.Column(7)
    Me.TextBox1.Value = Me.lstdisplay.Column(8)
    Me.TextBox2.Value = Me.lstdisplay.Column(9)
    Me.TextBox3.Value = Me.lstdisplay.Column(10)
    Me.TextBox4.Value = Me.lstdisplay.Column(11)
    Me.TextBox5.Value = Me.lstdisplay.Column(12)
    Me.TextBox6.Value = Me.lstdisplay.Column(13)
    Me.TextBox7.Value = Me.lstdisplay.Column(14)
    Me.TextBox8.Value = Me.lstdisplay.Column(15)
    Me.TextBox9.Value = Me.lstdisplay.Column(16)
    Me.Txtship.Value = Me.lstdisplay.Column(17)
    Me.TextBox10.Value = Me.lstdisplay.Column(18)
    Me.txtRecon.Value = Me.lstdisplay.Column(19)
    Me.txtPODate.Value = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yy")

Else
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why today's date?**

> The `Date` function returns a Variant (Date) containing the **current system date**.

whereas the `Now` function returns a Variant (Date) specifying the current date *and* **time** according to your computer's system date and time.

`Debug.Print Format(Date, "mm/dd/yy")` will show you the current system date formatted via pattern "mm/dd/yy", thus resulting in a string (e.g. `11/25/19`).

The syntax is simply `Date` (or `Now`) without any parameters.

C.f. MS Language Reference [Date function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/date-function) and [Now function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/now-function)

**Possible misunderstanding:** Don't confound the Date function with the data Type `Date` when declaring a variable, e.g. via `Dim myDate As Date`:-)

Comment: I figured it out. Where it says Date. I sued the actual textbox name and it started working. Thank you